# React local state showing empty inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code:

**App**

```
const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  async function fetchData() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setList(json));
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        accessor: "name"
      },
      {
        Header: "Email",
        accessor: "email"
      },
      {
        Header: "Action",
        accessor: "action",
        Cell: ({ cell }) => (
          <button
            className="btn btn-link ms-2"
            title="Delete"
            onClick={() => handleDelete(cell.row.original.id)}
          >
            Delete
          </button>
        )
      }
    ],
    []
  );
  const data = useMemo(() => [...list], [list]);

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    console.log("list", list);
    const originalList = [...list];
    const newList = originalList.filter((r) => r.id !== id);
    setList(newList);
    //try delete action to api
  };

  return (
    <AppTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      pageCount="3"
      fetchDataFn={fetchData}
    />
  );
};
```

**AppTable**

```
const AppTable = ({
  columns,
  data,
  pageCount: controlledPageCount,
  fetchDataFn
}) => {
  const tableInstance = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      manualSortBy: true,
      manualPagination: true,
      pageCount: controlledPageCount,
      manualGlobalFilter: true,
      autoResetSortBy: false,
      autoResetExpanded: false,
      autoResetPage: false,
      autoResetFilters: false
    },
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  );
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize, sortBy, globalFilter },
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setGlobalFilter
  } = tableInstance;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataFn();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <table
        className="table table-row-bordered table-hover gy-5 gx-5"
        {...getTableProps()}
      >
        <thead>
          {
            // Loop over the header rows
            headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
              // Apply the header row props
              <tr
                className="fw-bolder fs-5 text-gray-800"
                {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}
              >
                {
                  // Loop over the headers in each row
                  headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                    // Apply the header cell props
                    <th
                      {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}
                    >
                      <span
                        className={
                          column.isSorted
                            ? column.isSortedDesc
                              ? "table-sort-desc"
                              : "table-sort-asc"
                            : ""
                        }
                      >
                        {
                          // Render the header
                          column.render("Header")
                        }
                      </span>
                    </th>
                  ))
                }
              </tr>
            ))
          }
        </thead>
        {/* Apply the table body props */}
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {
            // Loop over the table rows
            rows.map((row) => {
              // Prepare the row for display
              prepareRow(row);
              return (
                // Apply the row props
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                  {
                    // Loop over the rows cells
                    row.cells.map((cell) => {
                      // Apply the cell props
                      return (
                        <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                          {
                            // Render the cell contents
                            cell.render("Cell")
                          }
                        </td>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </tr>
              );
            })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here, when ever, I click on delete button I am trying to get the original list, and filter the deleted row from the list and update it. But, unfortunately, current list is showing empty inside

```
  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    console.log("list", list); //showing empty
    const originalList = [...list];
    const newList = originalList.filter((r) => r.id !== id);
    setList(newList);
    //try delete action to api
  };
```

which is causing the table to be empty. Here, you can [test it](https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-action-on-react-table-lv0tcs?file=/src/App.js:1014-1238)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the delete function, your new list is dependent on the "previous" list. Therefore, you need to call setList with a callback like so:

```
const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    setList((prevList) =>
    {
        console.log("list", prevList);
        const newList = prevList.filter((r) => r.id !== id);
        return newList;
    });

    //try delete action to api
};
```

Replace that into your test code and notice that the previous list logs out correctly and that the deletion works right.

Answer (score 2):

add the list in useMemo dependency array ,

```
 const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        accessor: "name"
      },
      {
        Header: "Email",
        accessor: "email"
      },
      {
        Header: "Action",
        accessor: "action",
        Cell: ({ cell }) => (
          <button
            className="btn btn-link ms-2"
            title="Delete"
            onClick={() => handleDelete(cell.row.original.id)}
          >
            Delete
          </button>
        )
      }
    ],
    [list]
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought I might add an answer to cover why you're actually seeing an empty list:
Your problem is to do with closures and how you are memoizing your JSX that tries to use `handleDelete`:

```js
onClick={() => handleDelete(cell.row.original.id)}
```

Here, your code is referring to the first `handleDelete` function that gets created. By first I mean the initial `handleDelete` function that gets created on the initial mount/render/execution of your `App` component. When this function is defined, `list` at that point in time does not contain any values, so the `list` value that `handleDelete` accesses within its body is an empty array. Every time you re-render, your `handleDelete` function is recreated, and the function body for `handleDelete` has access to the new `list` that was created, but your code never uses these recreated versions of `handleDelete` due to your `useMemo()` call for the `columns` array. As you currently have this memoizing your array on the initial render/mount, the `handleDelete` function within that memoized function will refer to the `handleDelete` function created on the initial render - that being the one that only knows about an empty `list`.

To fix this, you can use a solution such as [Swiffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72584124/5648954), which is fine if you just want to update `list` (which you seem to want to do), but be aware that you will still have your closure issue outside of the state-setter function. If you were trying to simply just *read* the `list` value or some other state value within `handleDelete`, then you would need a different approach (which I've shown below). We can instead do something similar to [Faizal Hussain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72584091/5648954), so that the object is re-computed each time the list changes. However, rather than passing `list`, which isn't directly a dependency of your `useMemo()` array/object, I would instead address what the linter hints at doing in your sandbox:

> React Hook useMemo has a missing dependency: 'handleDelete'

You can add `handleDelete` as a dependency to your `useMemo()`:

```js
const columns = useMemo(..., [handleDelete]);
```

this way, you can clearly see that `columns` is dependent on `handleDelete` changing. At the moment, a new `handleDelete` is recreated each render, which would lead to a new `columns` object each rerender. To address this, we can use `useCallback()` to memoize the `handleDelete` function and have it only recreate when `list` changes (this would sit above the `useMemo()` for `columns`:

```js
const handleDelete = useCallback((id) => {
  const newList = list.filter((r) => r.id !== id);
  setList(newList);
}, [list]);
```

If you change `setList()` to use a state setter function `setList(list => ...);` then we can remove the `list` dependency. But with this approach, we can now see the correct values of our state values by accessing them directly from within the function itself and passing them as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time fixing it but the above solution did not work for me as I had two states. So I took an alternate and personally, I found this one cleaner.

I created a state as follows

```
const [itemToBeRemoved, setItemToBeRemoved] = useState("");
```

on the remove function, I set the id in the state

```
function handleDelete(id) {
    setItemToBeRemoved(id);
};
```

and finally, I created a useEffect for writing delete logic

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect called for remove", list);
    //Write your logic here
 }, [itemToBeRemoved]);
```